# Using svjour3 and spbasic, is it possible to move the year to the end of a reference?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, journal-publishing

I am writing a paper for submission to a springer journal that specifies the use of documentclass svjour3. The only bibliographystyle in the springer template for Harvard referencing is spbasic.

The author guidelines example of how a reference should look in the bibliography list is:

> Hamburger, C.: Quasimonotonicity, regularity and duality for nonlinear systems of partial differential equations. Ann. Mat. Pura Appl. 169, 321–354 (1995)

However, spbasic currently puts the year directly after the author name, for example:

> Goodhart C.A., Sunirand P., Tsomocos D.P. (2005) A risk assessment model for banks. Annals of Finance 1(2):197–224

Is there any way to force spbasic to adopt the different style, or can someone recommend a bibliographystyle which is compatible with the svjour3 documentclass that will achieve the correct format?

Comment: Ask the Springer folks about this. Perhaps you should use another bibliographystyle.